# character encoding of the HTML document was not declared codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, character-encoding

My CodeIgniter app has started to a freak error:

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

In the first visit, the page appears fine, just a message **"guimbu"**. If you refresh the page, the error appears until you clear the history of browser.
This happens only after second page-view. Take a look: http://guimbu.com/soon

- I've just opened ALL FILES with Sublime and saved to UTF-8; twice.
- I've just tried with all charset meta tags;
- This happens with ALL pages, including this simple page;

My autoload.php has this:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database', 'firephp', 'auth');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'log_helper', 'api_helper', 'string_helper');
$autoload['config'] = array('ci_opauth', 'rest', 'ci_auth');
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

How can I debug this problem?

**UPDATE:**

@sudhir, thanks for the answer, but I tried this many times. Actually the source code is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>guimbu</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>
<body>
    guimbu =)
</body>
</html>
```

And the error persists after second page-view =/
Maybe a problem with sessions?

**UPDATE with possibility:**

When I remove **session** and **auth** libraries from **autoload**, the problem doesn't happen. WTF? **auth** is a library I made for user authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND SOLUTION**

In the first lines of Session class constructor, it loads the String helper.
Yesterday I've created a helper called **string_helper.php** and this conflict was what crashing application.

I renamed my string_helper.php file and now everything works fine.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh that page you get a blank one, if you *view source* that page you'll see it's blank that is has a number count. My guess is that you're doing something when the page refreshes that sends a white space to the browser. I can only suggest not to close your files with `?>` and let php handle how your scripts will exit/die. There's some whitespace in your code that's causing that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed the ?> from 3 files, but the problem persists. I found a possibility: when I remove SESSION and AUTH libraries from AUTOLOAD, the problem doesn't happen. WTF? (auth is a library I made)

Comment: @Leabdalla then auth is the library that's sending a whitespace to the browser before anything else. Recheck

Comment: no success. I cleared **auth** just to **class auth { }** and the problem keeps on. is there a way can I debug this?

Comment: After removing the ?> I can autoload **auth** library. Now the problem happens only with **session** library.

Comment: @Leabdalla check if any whitespace exists before the <?php opening tag, same thing apply

Comment: @Leabdalla hey it was working for a second there, what did you do?

Comment: There's no one space before <?php opening tags, and no one echo or print() suspects... I've tried to load session inside **auth construct** but same problem

Comment: @Leabdalla sorry bud I have no clue what's going on, I can't help ya

Comment: I'll continue tomorrow. Maybe works, hahaha. Thanks man, greets from Brazil!

Comment: Does it happen on a clean install with the session library autoloaded?

Comment: @jeemusu, this is a project i'm working on for the last month. The problem started yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

try adding these in head section of your view:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```